# How to search through java files for attributes/ parameters of a certain type

Tags: java, static-analysis

I have a folder with java files. I would like to find out if a class contains an attribute of type X without compiling the project, i.e. I don't want to use reflection. How can I achieve this in a static way?

Comment: have you considered jboss roaster? https://github.com/forge/roaster#parsing-the-java-unit

Comment: Thanks, works like a charme! Mind posting this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [JBoss Forge's roster](https://github.com/forge/roaster) library?

```
String javaCode = "public class MyClass{ private String field;} public class AnotherClass {}";

JavaUnit unit = Roaster.parseUnit(javaCode);

JavaClassSource myClass = unit.getGoverningType();
JavaClassSource anotherClass = (JavaClassSource) unit.getTopLevelTypes().get(1);
```